# What recourse does someone have who was wrongfully arrested?

Tags: arrest

What recourse does someone have who was wrongfully arrested, and what outcome can someone expect from that recourse, in general and/or in California? If the charges that person was arrested for are dropped by the state, does that change the available recourse or expected outcomes?

Comment: "False Arrest" (a.k.a. Wrongful Arrest) is a common tort.  What sort of recourse do you mean?  Like to [expunge the record of the arrest](http://law.stackexchange.com/a/873/10)?  Or to claim civil damages against the police?

Comment: I'm looking for a list of available legal recourses. Expunging records and claiming civil damages are both good parts of an answer.